# EXC_BAD_ACCES in cxx_destruct error

Tags: xcode4, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I upgrade my lib to ARC and run as static lib in another non-arc project. I getting a EXC_BAD_ACCES and the debugger stop on `CLASSNAME.cxx_destruct`.

Is this a kind of new issue with ARC or is the same problems with EXC_BAD_ACCES (a nil reference?)

I'm confused because I stop in this method:

```
- (void)dealloc
{ 
    [self closeDb]; 
}
```

And work fine.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if there was a bug in ARC+Objective-C++, can you post more code about what you're actually doing?

Comment: @mamcx Ever find a solution? I am having the same crash!